# Click event also firing when check box check event within a row gets fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checkboxes within table individual rows.

I want some event to get fired , when elsewhere in the row click happens . But when a checkbox is checked , I do not want to fire any event.

This is my markup.

```
        <tbody data-bind="foreach:CustomerList">
            <tr onclick="removepage();" onmouseover="changeRowColor(this)" onmouseout="restoreRowColor(this)">

                <td>
                    <input class="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { Id: 'checkbox' + $data.Id },click:$parent.customerClick" type="checkbox">

                </td>
                <td class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="name" data-bind="text:customerName" />

                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text:siteName" />
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

So , if **removepage()** gets fired for everything , when

**customerClick()** happens , I do not want the **removepage()** to get fired.

I tried

```
    customerClick: function () {
        debugger;
        e.stopPropagation(); 
    },
```

but it did not work.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: In your code, `e` is undefined?!

Comment: Pass "e" without quotes as a parameter to your customerClick function and check again.

Answer (score 1):

your customerClick function should be:

```
customerClick: function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation(); 
    }
```

,

Answer (score 0):

You are using e without adding it as a parameter for the function
so just add e in your function()

```
customerClick: function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In java script you can stop the bubbling of event listner, because you have a few that listenrs to your event you can stop bubbling it to the other events...

**event.stopPropagation()**

is the method you looking for

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your events like this:

```js
$("#test > tbody > tr")
  .on("click", "td:not(.notfiring)", function(){
    alert("click tr");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="notfiring">
      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      Col 1
    </td>
    <td>
      Col 2
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope this helps you